# SQLAlchemy: Multiple ForeignKeys pointing to same table, some is optional with polymorphic inheritance enabled

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, polymorphism

I've created some base classes for an application which stores data using SQLAlchemy. One of the Base classes (Content) is polymorphic and have some general fields such as id, title, description, timestamps etc. Subclasses of this class is supposed to add additional fields which are stored in a separate table. I've created a standalone code sample which illustrates the concept better. The example contain the Base classes, some subclasses and some bootstrap code to create a sqlite database. The easiest way to get the example running by pasting the code into 'example.py', creating a virtualenv, installing SQLAlchemy into that virtualenv and using it's interpreter to run the example. The example contain some commented troublesome code, if that code is commented the example should run without errors (atleast it does here).

By uncommenting the commented code the example fails, and I'm not quite sure how to fix this - any help is superwelcome!

Example overview:

- It has some base classes (Base and Content).
- It has a Task class which extends Content.
- A Task may have subtasks, positional ordering should persist.
- It has a Project class (commented) which extends Content.
- Projects have a due_date and milestones (which is a list of Tasks)
- It has a Worklist class (commented) which extends Content.
- Worklists belong to an 'employee' and have tasks.

What I'm trying to achieve is having Task work as a standalone class, but additional classes may also have Tasks (such as Project and Worklist). I dont want to end up with several task/related tables, but rather want to utilize Content for this concept and attach Tasks in this 'generic' way.

Example code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import Boolean
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy import Date
from sqlalchemy import Unicode
from sqlalchemy import UnicodeText
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist import ordering_list
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref
from sqlalchemy.util import classproperty


class Base(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    @property
    def columns(self):
        return self.__mapper__.columns.keys()

    def add(self, **data):
        self.update(**data)
        db_session.add(self)
        db_session.flush()

    def delete(self):
        db_session.delete(self)
        db_session.flush()

    def update(self, **data):
        """
        Iterate over all columns and set values from data.
        """
        for attr in self.columns:
            if attr in data and data[attr] is not None:
                setattr(self, attr, data[attr])


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)
metadata = MetaData()
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
Base.metadata = metadata
Base.query = db_session.query_property()


class Content(Base):
    """
    Base class for all content. Includes basic features such as
    ownership and timestamps for modification and creation.
    """

    @classproperty
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return dict(
            polymorphic_on='type',
            polymorphic_identity=cls.__name__.lower(),
            with_polymorphic='*')

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    owner = Column(Unicode(128))
    title = Column(Unicode(128))
    description = Column(UnicodeText())
    creation_date = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    modification_date = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __init__(self, **data):
        self.add(**data)

    def update(self, touch=True, **data):
        """
        Iterate over all columns and set values from data.
        :param touch:
        :param data:
        :return:
        """
        super(Content, self).update(**data)
        if touch and 'modification_date' not in data:
            self.modification_date = datetime.utcnow()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Content) and self.id == other.id


def get_content(id):
    return Content.query.get(id)


class Task(Content):

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Content.id), primary_key=True)
    # content_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Content.id), nullable=True)

    done = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    position = Column(Integer, default=0)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('task.id'), nullable=True)

    tasks = relationship(
        'Task',
        cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan',
        backref=backref('parent', remote_side=id),
        foreign_keys='Task.parent_id',
        order_by=position,
        collection_class=ordering_list('position', reorder_on_append=True)
    )

def default_due_date():
    return datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=60)


# class Project(Content):
#
#     id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Content.id), primary_key=True)
#     due_date = Column(Date, default=default_due_date)
#
#     milestones = relationship(
#         'Task',
#         cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan',
#         backref=backref('content_parent', remote_side=id),
#         foreign_keys='Task.content_id',
#         collection_class=ordering_list('position', reorder_on_append=True)
#     )
#
#
# class Worklist(Content):
#
#     id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Content.id), primary_key=True)
#     employee = Column(Unicode(128), nullable=False)
#
#     tasks = relationship(
#         'Task',
#         cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan',
#         backref=backref('content_parent', remote_side=id),
#         foreign_keys='Task.content_id',
#         collection_class=ordering_list('position', reorder_on_append=True)
#     )


def main():
    db_session.registry.clear()
    db_session.configure(bind=engine)
    metadata.bind = engine
    metadata.create_all(engine)

    # Test basic operation
    task = Task(title=u'Buy milk')
    task = get_content(task.id)

    # assert Content attributes inherited
    assert task.title == u'Buy milk'
    assert task.done == False

    # add subtasks
    task.tasks = [
        Task(title=u'Remember to check expiration date'),
        Task(title=u'Check bottle is not leaking')
    ]

    # assert that subtasks is added and correctly ordered
    task = get_content(task.id)
    assert len(task.tasks) == 2
    assert [(x.position, x.title) for x in task.tasks] == \
           [(0, u'Remember to check expiration date'),
            (1, u'Check bottle is not leaking')]

    # reorder subtasks
    task.tasks.insert(0, task.tasks.pop(1))
    task = get_content(task.id)
    assert len(task.tasks) == 2
    assert [(x.position, x.title) for x in task.tasks] == \
           [(0, u'Check bottle is not leaking'),
            (1, u'Remember to check expiration date')]

    # # Test Project implementation
    # project = Project(title=u'My project')
    # milestone1 = Task(title=u'Milestone #1', description=u'First milestone')
    # milestone2 = Task(title=u'Milestone #2', description=u'Second milestone')
    # milestone1.tasks = [Task(title=u'Subtask for Milestone #1'), ]
    # milestone2.tasks = [Task(title=u'Subtask #1 for Milestone #2'),
    #                     Task(title=u'Subtask #2 for Milestone #2')]
    # project.milestones = [milestone1, milestone2]
    # project = get_content(project.id)
    # assert project.title == u'My project'
    # assert len(project.milestones) == 2
    # assert [(x.position, x.title) for x in project.milestones] == \
    #        [(0, u'Milestone #1'), (1, u'Milestone #2')]
    # assert len(Task.query.all()) == 8
    # assert isinstance(milestone1.content_parent, Project) == True
    #
    # # Test Worklist implementation
    # worklist = Worklist(title=u'My worklist', employee=u'Torkel Lyng')
    # worklist.tasks = [
    #     Task(title=u'Ask stackoverflow for help'),
    #     Task(title=u'Learn SQLAlchemy')
    # ]
    # worklist = get_content(worklist.id)
    # assert worklist.title == u'My worklist'
    # assert worklist.employee == u'Torkel Lyng'
    # assert len(worklist.tasks) == 2
    # assert len(Task.query.all()) == 10
    # assert isinstance(worklist.tasks[0].content_parent, Worklist) == True


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I'm sorry for this long example, wanted to supply something that worked standalone. Any help, comments on design or suggestions are greatly appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the example a bit and made it somewhat working. Instead of defining the additional ForeignKey on Task (content_id) I added it to the Content class as container_id

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import Boolean
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy import Date
from sqlalchemy import Unicode
from sqlalchemy import UnicodeText
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist import ordering_list
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref
from sqlalchemy.util import classproperty


class Base(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    @property
    def columns(self):
        return self.__mapper__.columns.keys()

    def add(self, **data):
        self.update(**data)
        db_session.add(self)
        db_session.flush()

    def delete(self):
        db_session.delete(self)
        db_session.flush()

    def update(self, **data):
        """
        Iterate over all columns and set values from data.
        """
        for attr in self.columns:
            if attr in data and data[attr] is not None:
                setattr(self, attr, data[attr])


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)
metadata = MetaData()
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
Base.metadata = metadata
Base.query = db_session.query_property()


class Content(Base):
    """
    Base class for all content. Includes basic features such as
    ownership and timestamps for modification and creation.
    """

    @classproperty
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return dict(
            polymorphic_on='type',
            polymorphic_identity=cls.__name__.lower(),
            with_polymorphic='*')

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    container_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('content.id'), nullable=True)
    # container = relationship('Content', foreign_keys=[container_id], uselist=False)

    type = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    owner = Column(Unicode(128))
    title = Column(Unicode(128))
    description = Column(UnicodeText())
    creation_date = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    modification_date = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __init__(self, **data):
        self.add(**data)

    @property
    def container(self):
        if self.container_id:
            return get_content(self.container_id)
        return None

    def update(self, touch=True, **data):
        """
        Iterate over all columns and set values from data.
        :param touch:
        :param data:
        :return:
        """
        super(Content, self).update(**data)
        if touch and 'modification_date' not in data:
            self.modification_date = datetime.utcnow()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Content) and self.id == other.id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{0} "{1}">'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.title)


def get_content(id):
    return Content.query.get(id)


class Task(Content):

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Content.id), primary_key=True)

    done = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    position = Column(Integer, default=0)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('task.id'), nullable=True)

    tasks = relationship(
        'Task',
        cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan',
        backref=backref('parent', remote_side=id),
        foreign_keys='Task.parent_id',
        order_by=position,
        collection_class=ordering_list('position', reorder_on_append=True)
    )

def default_due_date():
    return datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=60)


class Project(Content):

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Content.id), primary_key=True)
    due_date = Column(Date, default=default_due_date)

    milestones = relationship(
        'Task',
        cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan',
        foreign_keys='Task.container_id',
        collection_class=ordering_list('position', reorder_on_append=True)
    )


class Worklist(Content):

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Content.id), primary_key=True)
    employee = Column(Unicode(128), nullable=False)

    tasks = relationship(
        'Task',
        cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan',
        foreign_keys='Task.container_id',
        collection_class=ordering_list('position', reorder_on_append=True)
    )


def main():
    db_session.registry.clear()
    db_session.configure(bind=engine)
    metadata.bind = engine
    metadata.create_all(engine)

    # Test basic operation
    task = Task(title=u'Buy milk')
    task = get_content(task.id)

    # assert Content attributes inherited
    assert task.title == u'Buy milk'
    assert task.done == False

    # add subtasks
    task.tasks = [
        Task(title=u'Remember to check expiration date'),
        Task(title=u'Check bottle is not leaking')
    ]

    # assert that subtasks is added and correctly ordered
    task = get_content(task.id)
    assert len(task.tasks) == 2
    assert [(x.position, x.title) for x in task.tasks] == \
           [(0, u'Remember to check expiration date'),
            (1, u'Check bottle is not leaking')]

    # reorder subtasks
    task.tasks.insert(0, task.tasks.pop(1))
    task = get_content(task.id)
    assert len(task.tasks) == 2
    assert [(x.position, x.title) for x in task.tasks] == \
           [(0, u'Check bottle is not leaking'),
            (1, u'Remember to check expiration date')]

    # Test Project implementation
    project = Project(title=u'My project')
    milestone1 = Task(title=u'Milestone #1', description=u'First milestone')
    milestone2 = Task(title=u'Milestone #2', description=u'Second milestone')
    milestone1.tasks = [Task(title=u'Subtask for Milestone #1'), ]
    milestone2.tasks = [Task(title=u'Subtask #1 for Milestone #2'),
                        Task(title=u'Subtask #2 for Milestone #2')]
    project.milestones = [milestone1, milestone2]
    project = get_content(project.id)
    assert project.title == u'My project'
    assert len(project.milestones) == 2
    assert [(x.position, x.title) for x in project.milestones] == \
           [(0, u'Milestone #1'), (1, u'Milestone #2')]
    assert len(Task.query.all()) == 8
    container = milestone1.container
    assert isinstance(container, Project) == True

    # Test Worklist implementation
    worklist = Worklist(title=u'My worklist', employee=u'Torkel Lyng')
    worklist.tasks = [
        Task(title=u'Ask stackoverflow for help'),
        Task(title=u'Learn SQLAlchemy')
    ]
    worklist = get_content(worklist.id)
    assert worklist.title == u'My worklist'
    assert worklist.employee == u'Torkel Lyng'
    assert len(worklist.tasks) == 2
    assert len(Task.query.all()) == 10
    assert isinstance(worklist.tasks[0].container, Worklist) == True

    # Cleanup
    task = Task.query.filter_by(title=u'Buy milk').one()
    task.delete()
    project.delete()
    worklist.delete()
    assert len(Task.query.all()) == 0


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The `container` relationship on the Content-class did not work as expected, it returned None if I did not specify `task.container = somecontainer`. Instead I opted for a property method instead which returns None or container object. I'll investigate the subject further to perhaps find a more optimal solution. Suggestions or alternative solutions are still very very welcome.